# detect the language of input?

Tags: php

I have an input in my form, I wanna find a solution to determine which language is typed in..( is it English, french, arabic, or Hebrew ..)...

in PHP script, also I use UTF-8 encode.

Comment: I look for a solution using PHP language... thanks all..

Answer (score 5):

Use google translate API
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Detect

On server side, try [this](http://www.plentyofcode.com/2008/10/google-translation-api-translate-on.html).I haven't tried it though.

And please do read the [terms](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/terms.html) before using it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Google translate API for that.

Answer (score 2):

Google have an API for language detection that you could use:

http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Detect

Answer (score 2):

You can use a perl script for that, see:
http://odur.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/Demo/

Several competing/alternative products are also listed on that page.